Kernel support for displaying fonts with rotations and reflections (with or without Unicode support)
I am posting to this group because I was wondering whether the Linux kernel can be extended to support the feature of displaying fonts with reflections and rotations, whether these are stored as part of Unicode or not.
Here is a link to the vim feature I requested. Vim is the de facto system administrator text editor on Unix and Linux systems, and, is also, used, by various developers (in various incarnations).
That's why I posted there.
What changes to the kernel and Unicode would be necessary to support this feature?
When will these features be added?
Is there any mention of these in the TODO list for kernel development?
When will they at least be added to the TODO list (perhaps with a reference to this post)?
Thank you for your support.
Thank you for your development.
Thank you for your answers.
Thanks.
